# automated Socrata download

Tags: excel, odata, socrata

I need to download data from Socrata unattended, i.e., the program starts up as scheduled and runs, downloads data, then ends; all without human interaction.

I found a reference to downloading to Excel via OData and thought I would try that since I can schedule an Excel process to start unattended.

I have Excel 2010 but there is no reference to OData in the Get External Data from Other Sources drop down.  How do I add OData to that drop down list of other sources?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be under "From Other Source > From OData Feed". Here's a [howto document](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-to-an-odata-feed-HA104019824.aspx).

I think it might require Office 2010 Professional, but I'm not positive. Another option would be to use the "From Text" web query option, [as documented here](http://www.kimgentes.com/worshiptech-web-tools-page/2010/8/19/web-connecting-csv-files-as-external-data-to-excel-spreadshe.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PowerPivot for Excel which is part of SQL Server 2012. 
You don't need SQL Server on your machine.